# Definition of Big O notation

Tags: complexity-theory

I am an experienced programmer who understands the Big O notation (constant, linear, logN, NlogN, polynomial etc). I can analyse algorithms and find their complexities. But I am not a Computer Science Engineer. Everything is mostly self-taught.

Today, I was looking up Sedgewick's book, chapter on analysis of Algorithms. This is how he defines the Big O algorithm

> A function g(N) is said to be O(f(N)) if there exist constants
> c<sub>o</sub> and N<sub>o</sub> such that g(N) is less than
> c<sub>o</sub>f(N) for all N > N<sub>o</sub>

I can't understand this at all. What do I need to know to understand this?

Comment: Watch YouTube videos for support.

Comment: If you have a code that executes in a time g(N) for given N samples, then the O(f(N)) is the upper bound of that function, or the big O notation. This means f(N) would be greater than g(N) for values greater than some number.  It means that g(N) would be less than f(N) and f(N) would hence provide the maximum time it could take.

Comment: @Redvelvetpastry what are c0 & N0?

Comment: They are arbitrary numbers for which the value holds true. For example, if g(N)=x, then f(N)=x^2. Here, f(N) would be greater than g(N) when x>1, so N0 here is 1 and c0 can be a number greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

In very simple terms, it means that your function takes 25 * n + 17 CPU cycles, or anything of this form, it can be said to be O(n). We only care about the fastest-growing part of the equation (that's the meaning of the N > N0 bit: for sufficiently-large values of N, we can say 25*n + 17 < 26n), and we do not actually care about any constant factors either (because we are dealing with an abstract concept like "complexity", not "CPU cycles" or "execution time", all of which are impractical to measure and dependent on your implementation anyway).

This allows us to simplify stuff like O(n^3 + 7*n^2 + 5 log n + 17) to simply O(n^3), which is a lot shorter and still conveys all we need to know, because for large n, all the other parts will be negligible.